# Check if boost::asio buffer data is present before read()

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to port a piece of software I wrote with Unix sockets to a version with TCP sockets, using boost::asio. The program is intended to run on a Linux machine.

In the earlier version of the code (using Unix sockets) I used a simple check to see if there was new data on the socket buffer, and then proceeding with reading predictably structured data:

```
    ioctl(s_c, FIONREAD, &socketstatus);
    while (socketstatus > 0)
    {// do receive stuff
    ioctl(s_c, FIONREAD, &socketstatus);}
```

Is there any way to do something similar with boost::asio?
Or some better alternatives?

Thank you in advance
CB

Comment: did you already read through the very good collection of boost asio [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) and the boost asio [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html)? maybe you find answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bytes_readable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/bytes_readable.html), this implements what you want.

> Implements the FIONREAD IO control command.

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service); 
...
boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable command(true);
socket.io_control(command);
std::size_t bytes_readable = command.get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the native descriptor from a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` using the `native()` [method](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native.html), which should work just fine with your existing code.

Though, I question your motivation for doing this. The Asio event reactor implements polling mechanics using `epoll` on [Linux](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html). There should be no need to poll a socket for reading or writing outside of the `io_service` event loop.

Comment: In which sense there should be no need? My goal is to read a fixed amount of data only when data is available. Is there a smarter way of doing this?

Comment: @Carlo the `io_service` does the polling for you. When the completion condition you request with `async_read` or `async_write` has been met, the completion handler is invoked.