# Check for data on boost::asio socket before read? Or should I use async_read()?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am new to socket IO.  I've been using `socket::read_some()` to pull data from the socket.  I am confident I'm asking the socket for data more often than data is available on the socket, so it appears that the blocking nature of 'read_some()` is slowing execution of my program to the rate at which data comes over the socket.  I'd like to check for data then move on if nothing is present.  My code currently looks like this:

```
unsigned char incomingData[PARTIAL_PKT_BUFF_SIZE];
int numRead = 0;
numRead =
  _socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(incomingData,PARTIAL_PKT_BUFF_SIZE));
```

If I implement the code in the first answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748412/check-if-boostasio-buffer-data-is-present-before-read), it looks like I would be using a `bytes_readable` object to control the socket, I could then do check to see if the `bytes_readable::get()` returns greater than zero then read the socket.

It looks like an async_read() might do the job, but I must admit I don't really understand it.  It looks like I'd need to register a callback, which suggests that I may then need to put some safety mechanism around the buffer.  Am I right in thinking this is a more complex solution?

Comment: Asynchronous IO is slightly more complicated, but the trade off is almost always worth the effort.  My vote would absolutely move to `async_read()`.  If you didn't want to use asynchronous IO, why even use boost over plain old sockets?

Comment: A big part of my attraction to boost is it's platform independence.

Comment: @2NinerRomeo I believe Chad's point is you don't really gain much by using boost.asio but not using asynchronous I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like to check for data then move on if nothing is present

you have just described the methodology known as polling.

> It looks like an `async_read()` might do the job, but I must admit I
>   don't really understand it.

correct, `async_read()` is the perfect solution here.

> It looks like I'd need to register a
>   callback, which suggests that I may then need to put some safety
>   mechanism around the buffer. Am I right in thinking this is a more
>   complex solution?

you will need a callback for the event loop to notify your application when the read operation has completed. You don't need any sort of safety mechanism. It is not a complex solution once you wrap your head around the inverted flow control. There are several [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) and a [tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3.html) showing you how to write asynchronous I/O programs. Study them and ask questions on Stackoverflow if you have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

```
asio::streambuf s_buf;
asio::async_read_until(sock, s_buf, '\n', std::bind(completionHandler, std::placeholders::_1));
std::string message;
std::istream input_stream(&s_buf);
std::getline(input_stream, message);
std::cout << message << std::endl;
// Whenever it successfully read an entire message ; it will call the function completion handler. 
void completionHandler(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (ec != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Error occured! Error code = " << ec.value() << ". Message: " << ec.message();
        return;
    }
}
```